# jBPM creating duplicate tasks after timer event : Multiple instances running

Tags: hibernate, drools, jbpm, kie, bitronix

We are providing jBPM services to different applications.

The service is deployed on multiple pool and multiple instances of the services are running. But recently after updating the Hibernate to 5.1.3+ versions we are getting duplicate tasks.

For single pool, single instance there are no duplicates getting generated and only the tasks which are after the timer event have duplicate problem. Not always it generated duplicates but mostly.

[image]

Always the Notify Manager is duplicating and assume Remind Sys Admin task is not there.
In the jBPM cancel/interrupt check box is selected already

Can someone suggest something to debug or fix?

I have referred this [link](https://answers.laserfiche.com/questions/88987/Timer-event-duplicating-tasks) but its confusing what they want us to do. Above select/deselect I have already tried.

Comment: looking for help....anyone please?

Comment: guys help please? is the question not clear?